# Facebook Page in Android Webview

Tags: android, facebook, android-webview, facebook-android-sdk

I want to open a facebook page in my app using webView but when i do this, it keeps showing the page and at the top ask me either to sign in or sign up

but when i click sign in it redirect me to the facebook page in the default browser and it show the page because i m logged in - in the default browser

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    WebView w = new WebView(this); 

//add this to your code

     w.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
     w.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");


//and this class also 
 private class Callback extends WebViewClient{  //HERE IS THE MAIN CHANGE. 

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return (false);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```